# How to remove a css class using jquery in a certain screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've a div with a class and when the window is resized to a mobile view-port I want that class to be removed.

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can simply use media CSS queries.

Comment: Yes that is correct. You should use media css.

Comment: @Mohamed, Please check my snippet code answer.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Thanks mate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this just using media queries. But still if you're looking for a solution in jquery then you can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass) method like this:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
  var size = $(window).width();//get updated width when window is resized
  $('.box').toggleClass('box', size > 1067);//remove class only in less or equal to 1067
}).resize();//trigger resize on load
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 480) {
          $('#yourDivId').removeClass('box');
     }
  else{}
});
```

Comment: This is also helpful. If don't want to use media css.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS3 media queries you can do this.

**CSS3 Code:**

```
/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
 and (min-device-width: 320px) 
 and (max-device-width: 480px)
 and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
     .box {
        //reset all css properties set for box class.
     }
 }
```

This is the only possible solution in CSS3, since CSS cant modify the DOM or its structure.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code and you can check my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Narendrad/p07etktk/1/embedd/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">dd</div>
```

**JQ:**

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    var screen = $(window);//Window instance...
    var mobileWidth = 400;//Mobile width...

    //If mobile view then remove div class, set div class other then mobile view...
    screen.width() < mobileWidth ? $('div').removeClass('box') : $('div').addClass('box');

    //Set window current width for temporary check...
    $('div').text($(window).width());//Comment this if you don't want it.
}).trigger('resize');
```

Hope this help you well..

Answer (score 0):

use this may help you in style

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .box {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

or you may use

```
  @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
        .box {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK, this will hide the `div` with class `box`. But he wants the class to be removed. But, I would surely like to know how can we achieve this using CSS.

Comment: @Alorika: CSS cant modify the DOM , it can change only its presentation. so you need to use jquery for this or just reset the CSS properties of `.box` class

Comment: by using media qurey you can achieve this

Comment: by using media query you can hide the class as put in html<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">